# Video background not working in Divi Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, video, divi

I'm trying to set the background of a full width section to be a video but when I view it in a browser it is just a grey background with a loading spinner. I'm getting these errors in the console and I'm not sure what they mean. Any ideas? TIA!

[Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8RNN.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a possible conflict. Are you using a plugin for the video background or one of Divi's modules? I would try deactivating plugins one by one to see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

divi is the worst theme ever, builder is super slow, many issues, dont use divi on your website, use elementor or page bakery supp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).